# Find slowest loading / longest time to generate pages

Tags: 7, debugging, performance

Is it possible to find pages that take the longest time to generate? I am aware Devel can collect query log per page, but is there a module that collects these per page and displays a list of slowest pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Performance Logging and Monitoring](http://drupal.org/project/performance) module was split out from the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module last summer, but is mostly the same.

The summary logging page is sortable by all of the table columns.  For example, if you want to show the slowest pages first, you just need to click on the "MS (MAX)" column heading until it sorts descending.  The direct URL would be at `/admin/reports/performance-logging/summary?sort=desc&order=ms+%28Max%29`

You can also do a manual query on the database if that is where you are storing results:

```
SELECT *
FROM {performance_summary} performance_summary
ORDER BY ms_max DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a roundabout way of getting at the data, but if you have Google Analytics setup on your site, it's also possibly the fastest and easiest. Specifically, check out the [Site Speed](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2012/03/measure-your-websites-performance-with.html) reports.

GA uses the new "HTML5 Navigation Timing" spec, which allows it to track server response time, latency between server and client, as well as the actual browser execution time.. and you can slice and dice the data by any of those dimensions.